# Which sqlite3 library to use for iPhone 3 development

Tags: iphone, sqlite

I'm new to iPhone dev and am using sqlite3 but there seem to be two different sqlite libraries available: libsqlite3.0.dylib and libsqlite3.dylib

Which is the best to use?  What's the difference?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `libsqlite3.dylib` library will be a symbolic link to the latest version supported in your Xcode installation. So whenever you install the latest Xcode and recompile your app, you'll get the latest 3.x library installed for free.

This can include both performance and feature enhancements, but can also include new bugs. You could pick the specific version, i.e. `libsqlite3.0.dylib`, if you want to play it safe.

Answer (score 1):

The iPhone OS X contains 3, however there is an issue with Tiger having a different version. If that's what you're using then it's worth getting the latest version and upgrading to avoid issues.